# Stack Overflow for Teams not visible through https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/?

Tags: discussion

We would like to use the new [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/05/03/stack-overflow-for-teams-is-now-available/?cb=1) and I have setup a trial of that.

I can see the team content when working via https://stackoverflow.com/ but **not** when working via https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/ which is the URL we use most as a Salesforce ISV. So it appears these are separate worlds, which is a pity, although a common login works across them.

What is going on here?

(I've also asked this question in a comment on the announcement page.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did get a response to my comment on [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/05/03/stack-overflow-for-teams-is-now-available/?cb=1) from the author that:

> Hi Keith – currently Teams are only available on stackoverflow.com but
>   not on any of the other Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 2):

[I asked this on twitter](https://twitter.com/jclark_org/status/992040307284996096) yesterday.  I don't think SO employee who answered quite got the question, so I've pointed him here.